# How do I compare values between two different workbooks in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 worksheets. They both contain a column named "ID" and a column named "purchaseDate".

How can I check if both of these columns are the same in both workbooks?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. Just to tell you if both columns in both sheets are identical? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, you can use the [Inquire Addin](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42).

Comment: If they are sorted the same, use `exact()` function.